# :name, :forname to :fullname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Its the first time i work with json in Rails. In the search action from the patients controller i defined:

```
     format.json { render json: @patients}
```

So now this resource gives me such a output:

```
[{"id":73551,"typ":null,"name":"Beck","forname":"Ana","birthday":"1945-06-14","titel":"",department_id":2,"tot":null},
```

I would like to change the ouput to something like:

```
[{"id":73551,"fullname":"Beck, Ana"},{...
```

How do i do this? Thanks!

Update! Now i have:

```
....
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.json { render json: as_json(@patients)}
      end
  end

  def as_json(options={})
     { 
         :id => self.id,
         :fullname => self.name + ", " + self.forname
     } 
  end
```

But somehow i get the error

> undefined method `id' for #

Comment: Did you try `@patients.select([:id, :fullname])` ?

Comment: Oh very good! Thanks! The only problem that stays is that i have no datafield `fullname` but `forname` and `name` that should be connectet to `fullname = name, forname` Maybe you can post it as a asnwer? Thanks

Comment: You need to put the `as_json` method in your `Patient` Model. Not in your Controller.

Comment: Now i get `
IOError in PatientsController#search
not opened for reading` in `format.json { render json: as_json(@patients)}`

Comment: `json: @patients`. The `as_json` method should automatically be called by rails during the serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` clause should do the work : `@patients.select([:id, :fullname, :whateveryouneed])`

---

For the second problem, you may consider overidding `Patient.as_json` method :

```
def as_json(options={})
     { 
         :id => self.id,
         :fullname => self.name + ", " + self.forname
     } 
end
```

Comment: But fullname should contain `:name, forename` ! Sorry

Comment: I tried something like you said! You can see it in the Update! But it wont work! What did i wrong? Thanks